# SQL - Get Numerical Day of Month/Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Using SQL Server 2005:

How can I get the numerical day of the month and day of the quarter in a query?

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEPART(dy, @DATE) AS DayOfYear
    --, <something> AS DayOfQuarter
    --, <something> AS DayOfMonth
    , DATEPART(dw, @DATE) AS DayOfWeek
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: +1 Just learned some new tricks working with dates through Cade Roux's answer becuase of your question, thanks, though I have answered half of it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = GETDATE()

SELECT DATEPART(dy, @DATE) AS DayOfYear
    , DATEDIFF(d, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @DATE), 0), @DATE) + 1 AS DayOfQuarter
    , DAY(@Date) AS DayOfMonth
    , DATEPART(dw, @DATE) AS DayOfWeek
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the day of quarter, this will demande a bit of further investigate on my side. Despite, I guess that for the day of month, this would simply be the date itself:

```
select DATEPART(D, @DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 DATEPART(year, '12:10:30.123')
,DATEPART(month, '12:10:30.123')
,DATEPART(day, '12:10:30.123')
,DATEPART(dayofyear, '12:10:30.123')
,DATEPART(weekday, '12:10:30.123');
```